# Is antivirus software on a Linux desktop more or less secure?

Tags: linux, anti-virus

On a Linux desktop (*not* a mail server for Windows machines, or similar), but sharing a network with other Windows machines, would you say your network is more or less secure running a Linux antivirus product? Or does it make no difference either way?

I'd argue that you're extremely unlikely to end up in a situation where you're unknowingly causing problems for Windows users because you're silently sending viruses around the network. If anything, on a closed network, repeatedly transferring the updates from an external source onto the Linux desktop is likely to reduce your security, if anything.

Thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is antivirus software on a Linux desktop more or less secure?](http://superuser.com/questions/200977/is-antivirus-software-on-a-linux-desktop-more-or-less-secure)

Comment: @honk, if you comment on both duplicates, the end result may be that _both_ are closed as duplicate...

Comment: @Peter: ok, I shouldn't have done this, but after voting for this one first I wished I could have undone it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes

Comment: Please review the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq). Super User is **not a discussion forum**.

Answer (score 0):

Linux and Windows viruses are completely different in their nature ) Normal antivirus for Win knows about windows threats, and vice versa for Linux. So you need to catch linux-virus that can send viruses by network to the windows devices ) But such linux-virus must be stoped by your linux-antivirus )

Answer (score 0):

As cross-platform viruses do exist, your network is always more secure with anti-virus.

I may draw flames here from Linux advocates who maintain it is unattackable, but in my book everything is attackable. The latest router hacks are in effect Linux exploits.

As ancient wisdom says: "Better safe than sorry".